# How do you edit(i.e. delete row) uiTableView when using sections?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Hello and Thanks to all.  I have a table view where I allow the user to change to a sectioned view.  All is well in standard view however when the user switches to sectioned view I crash when I try to delete a row with the  (-commitEditingStyle:) function.   What am I missing in this function?  How should I delete a row when It's sectioned? (I load my Table from a plist wchich is a dictionary of Arrays. Each index being a row in the tableview.)

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     if ([strTitle isEqualToString:@"sectionView"]) {

         @try {


         if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
             // Delete the row from the data source.
           //  NSMutableDictionary *book =[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
             NSMutableDictionary *mynewList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
             mynewList = [[self.TitleDis valueForKey:[[[self.TitleDis allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
             NSMutableArray *sectionRow = [mynewList objectForKey:@"Dis"];


             [sectionRow removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

             [mynewList writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

             //
             [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

         } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
             // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
         }   
         }
         @catch (NSException *exception) {
             NSLog(@"hello error...%@",exception);
         }



     }

     else {
    /////////////////////// STANDARD VIEW 

    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source.
        [distribArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        //
        //        NSMutableArray *contents = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        //        [contents addObject:myMasterList];
        //        //[contents addObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:arraydata.text,distroName.text,destorEmail.text, nil]];

        [distribArray writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];

        //
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];

    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view.
    }   
         //////////////////////////////////
     }
}
```

CONSOLE:  -[__NSCFString removeObjectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xe4bd3f0

As you can see I have been toying with the format....not sure what to try next ??? Thanks.

what I mean by sectioned:[image]

Comment: what do you mean by 'sectioned view'? do you mean the grouped style of the table view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems are here. The below line will create a leak and should not be used in this way.

```
NSMutableDictionary *mynewList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
             mynewList = [[self.TitleDis valueForKey:[[[self.TitleDis allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Instead of this you can put it as,

```
NSMutableDictionary *mynewList = [[self.TitleDis valueForKey:[[[self.TitleDis allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Another thing is,

`[mynewList objectForKey:@"Dis"];` is not always an array and it is sometimes coming as string. Check your data structure and confirm if it is an array.

Try like this,

```
id obj = [mynewList objectForKey:@"Dis"];
NSLog(@"%@", [[obj class] description]);
```

and check what is the data type of `obj` printed in `NSLog`. Confirm it is `NSMutableArray` and not `NSString`.

Comment: `mynewList` should not be inited and re-assigned as the OP does. But is does not create a memory leak if you compile with ARC. (And I assume ARC because there is not a single retain or release in the code.)

Comment: Yes that's true, if ARC is used. But still the first line doesn't make any sense to have it that way. He can directly assign it. But I am not sure if ARC is used in this code. That was just a very generic comment.

Answer (score 0):

So for one, you've got:

```
NSMutableDictionary *mynewList = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
mynewList = [[self.TitleDis valueForKey:[[[self.TitleDis allKeys] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)] objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

where you are allocing mynewList and then immediately overwriting it.

But I think you should probably check the type of sectionRow in the debugger. My guess is that it's an NSString.

It's pretty hard to tell what's going on without knowing a bit more about your data structures.